# Creating a New button Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to create a New button (icon only) next to the 3 dots button in the ActionBar. This is the code I tried, but it adds it as child of the 3 dots button.

**main_activity_actions.xml:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/create_game"
        android:menuCategory="container"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="@string/new_game"
        android:titleCondensed="nieuw spel">
    </item>

</menu>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Also, how can I find out what default icons I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show icons in the action bar, you can add the line `android:showAsAction="always"` to your XML item. Still Android would show it only if it judges there is adequate space in the action bar. If you strictly always want to show your button, you can define and set a custom layout for your action bar.

You can download the default icon set for action bar from https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html

Comment: How do I add the icon set to my project?

Comment: You can copy the icon you want to use to your drawables folder in your project and then add this resource as background in your XML item like this: android:background="@drawable/myninepatch"

Answer (score 1):

try it

**/res/menu/activity_main.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_save"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
        android:title="@string/menu_guardar"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_new"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:title="@string/menu_nuevo"/>
</menu>
```

**MainActivit.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //...

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}

//onClic item
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_new:
            Log.i("ActionBar", "Nuevo!");
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_save:
            Log.i("ActionBar", "Guardar!");;
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_settings:
            Log.i("ActionBar", "Settings!");;
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And you can download All IconPack here:

https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can inflate a custom actionbar for adding buttons with images like this:

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActionBar()
            .getThemedContext()
            .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View customActionBarView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_custom, null);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(
            ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM,
            ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
    actionBar.setCustomView(customActionBarView,
        new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Where _actionbar_custom.xml_ would be your layout resource, usually a `LinearLayout` with whatever components you want.